# Set default organization view when logging in to GitHub

Tags: github

If I am a part of multiple GitHub organizations, how can I set which GitHub organization I view by default when logging in?

Answer (score 3):

I could not find a way to do this in Github, but you can save a shortcut to use the organisation url to login on Github, so after login you will be viewing it by default.

https://github.com/your-organization

And passwords auto complete works okay.